# How to install Magelia webstore in IIS?

Tags: c#, orchardcms, shopping-cart

I am facing problem in configuring Magelia store services. I have been working for Magelia-Orchard integration.

**Server Error in '/store/Services' Application
Could not load file or assembly 'Magelia.WebStore.Runtime.Web' or one of its dependencies.**

Although, I am able to navigate to admin panel properly.

I get same error when I try to obtain metadata using browser.
I also tried using localiis services url as input to magelia responsive visual studio template => Nothing was fetched.

I have installed Magelia.WebStore.2.4.331.6 binaries.

```
Here are the steps I have followed:

 1. Importing deployment package into IIS, new website running IIS 4.5
    App pool localiis:82/store
 2. For SQL setup I had selected auto attach db, on .\SQLEXPRESS
 3. Selected option to install default products & default users
    (undeletable)
 4. Browse to Default.aspx located in root folder
 5. Completed registration process  

How I have deployed:
```

Imported deployment package directly from IIS & rest of the process is automated. So how this assembly could be missed out?
Could not load file or assembly `'Magelia.WebStore.Runtime.Web'` or one of its dependencies.

```
What I have tried to diagnose issue:
```

I checked heartbeat of services by trying to ping below url:
**www.siteroot/store/services/Administration/Heartbeat.svc/ping**
ping returned false. I read on codeplex that it should return true.

Answer (score 1):

Web Http Activation was not enabled on my PC. I had to enable it by going to control panel -> Add features -> WCF 4.5 features -> Enable Web Http Activation.

I hope it would help someone installing magelia.